# Finding memory corruption bugs in Linux and FreeBSD

Tags: linux, freebsd, memory, ram

In windows, we can enable page heap verification using gflags to catch memory corruption bugs more easily. Is there a similar service/program for Linux and FreeBSD operating systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Applications_Debugging_Techniques/Heap_corruption

E.g., electric fence will do this.

Valgrind will also do this and much more http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html